# "There's only 5 minutes left until 6 o'clock." Is this correct?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?

> There's only 5 minutes left until 6 o'clock.

I'm wondering if the word 'until/till' can be used to point out the remaining duration of a certain time. I've read from a certain website that the word 'until' can't be used to describe numbers or quantity, and I should instead use 'up to'. But the sentence, "There's only 5 minutes left up to 6 o'clock," doesn't sit right with me.

Can someone explain this to me?

This is the link of the website where I got this:
https://www.crownacademyenglish.com/prepositions-time-by-until/

Comment: It's grammatically correct, and I suppose there _might_ be circumstances in which you would say it that way instead of "It's five to six" or "It's 5.55".

Comment: Looking at the link, the comments about not using until/till with numbers are referring to countable quantities; used with times it's normal to use until/till.

Comment: I might prefer *There are only 5 minutes left ...* but the *until* looks fine

Comment: @Henry. It's not incorrect in this case, but time intervals are usually treated as unitary composites. And I'd definitely once have marked '3½ years are a long time' wrong. // 'It's the Joneses' is seen as acceptable nowadays, with a 'number-blind' modern treatment of 'It's' to cover 'It is/are'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you suggesting that it used to be more acceptable to say "it are the Joneses"?

Comment: 6 o'clock isn't a number or a quantity. It's a time. That website doesn't say there's any rule against using "until" with time. In fact it specifically says several times that we use "until" with time.

Comment: @Marc Oops; tea called. 'Here's' certainly covers 'Here are' as well as 'Here is'; 'It's' (no prior reference)  is now regularly used with both plural-form and singular-form complements/delayed subjects. 'It are ....' has of course never been acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is perfectly idiomatic. The reason it works, despite the rule about not using until with a number is because the thing it is being used with is *not* a number. That is, "until" is not being used with only the "6", but rather with the whole fragment "6 o'clock". There's even an example of that use in the link you provided:

> I am going to study until 9 o’clock.

Now while the phrase you provide is completely acceptable, and is a common way of saying the proposition in question, I guess one could quibble slightly at the "There's" at the beginning, being a contraction of "There is..." It's arguable that because it is referring to more than one minute, it should be "There are..." And in fact I myself, as a native speaker, may well say:

> There're only 5 minutes left until 6 o'clock!

But I'm probably unusual in that respect.

Comment: Not unusual at all, this is a way of saying what "the time" is. "It" is the time, what follows is any arbitrary way of expressing the time. Recommended action is remove personal details about the author and replace them them with this information as support.

Answer (score 0):

I believe native speakers could use any of the following.

There's only five minutes until six! (Or, possibly: There are only five minutes until six)

It's just five minutes before six o'clock!

It's only five minutes until six!

Six o'clock is in just five minutes!

It is interesting that a number of minutes, which would seem to require a plural verb, is usually treated as a (singular) interval or period (with a singular verb).

Comment: In your construction "it" is the subject of "is" with "it" being the time. "The time is 5 minutes until 6"